# How to add a simple online payment transaction?

Tags: 7

My client ask me to add a simple online transaction system to his drupal 7 site. Payment amount for his users are actually fixed for example 100$, 250$ and 350$. Also he wants link that transaction with his local bank and as optional he wants add the pay-pal also.

Could anyone please tell me how can I start to integrating this? I checked the drupal-ecommerce kicksart but I believe thats more advanced to this. However if anyone can instruct me to optimize it's requirement my client needs then it would be helpful.

I also checked Drupal https://drupal.org/project/simple_payments but since it's not supporting for the drupal 7 I've not much read on it.

Comment: "Also he wants link that transaction with his local bank and as optional..." I don't understand this, can you clarify?

Comment: Actually I meant, if the user finished his payment, it should transact to his company bank account which is in Srilanka.

Comment: I think that any payment gateway should be able to deposit the funds properly into his bank account, be it PayPal or Stripe or whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that Commerce Kickstart is too advanced for what you need. You'd end up spending a lot of time configuring "off" a lot of stuff just to give your users a simple checkout.

I've setup several simple custom payment solutions for Drupal sites using **[Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform)** and **[Stripe.com](http://www.stripe.com)**.

Here's an example of a Stripe/Webform component: https://drupal.org/sandbox/jlyon/1472346

Basically you'd build out the component that captures their CC info and submits it to Stripe via javascript, then run the charge on the server side using the token that Stripe gives you. This gets you out of the bulk of PCI compliance (you just need to have SSL enabled and ensure that you don't let any CC info be sent to your server). Since Webform is easy to use and you can add whatever form elements you'd like, you can quickly capture the right customer info and set the "product" or dollar amount in a dropdown field, then run the charge in a `_validate()` function.

Not quite plug and play but also not a lot of development time to get a solid working solution.

**Edit:** You mentioned PayPal – you could provide that as an alternate purchase opition and use a simple paypal button to send them on their merry way; also https://drupal.org/project/webform_paypal

**Edit 2:** After thinking about Ryan's comment a bit, I would suggest you first grab [Commerce module](https://drupal.org/project/commerce) and tinker with it for a while. You may find that it gets you what you need. I have really enjoyed implementing some custom, lean payment systems using Stripe where a traditional "checkout" workflow wasn't appropriate, but there's no need to reinvent the wheel if it fits.

Comment: Actually, in the original question, the contention was against Commerce Kickstart being too much for the use case, which is definitely true. Drupal Commerce itself is not, especially if we're talking about multiple payment methods for the same product with any hope of simple unified accounting and integration into the rest of the site. I can't think of a single thing you'd have to configure "off" to have a simple checkout - I build them all the time. I'd highly recommend the original poster pursue Drupal Commerce on its own without all that comes in Commerce Kickstart 2.x.

Comment: Great point Ryan. I was thinking of the Commerce Kickstart profile specifically. I will revise my post.

Comment: Thanks Ryan and Charlie S I'll follow your instruction and let you know how much success I'm.

Answer (score 3):

The [Payment](https://drupal.org/project/payment) module provides a simple to use payment processing API for Drupal 7.

Comment: Thanks for this but Is it possible for you to give some example sites which is using this module?

Comment: I'm currently using it for an unreleased project. Other than that, I don't directly known of any sites using Payment. But, according to the stats on Drupal.org, 810 sites are using it (see https://drupal.org/project/usage/payment).

Comment: I'm currently looking at using this module with [Webform Payment Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_paymethod_select) and `stripe_payment` or `paypal_payment`, which seems promising.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider the [Webform Stripe](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_stripe) module which provides a lightweight, powerful integration between Webform and Stripe. From the project page:

> Webform Stripe adds super simple Stripe integration to Webforms, so that submissions can be "purchased".
>
> With this, you can use webforms for event registrations, online donations, or even for simple products where you need to gather additional information from a user.
>
> It uses Stripe Checkout to collect payments as the form is submitted.
>
> There are lots of ways to collect payment for Webforms. Most of them are difficult or require lots of modules. This is super simple solution. If you require more complex workflows or integration with your store, consider the myriad of options available for Commerce, Ubercart, or Payment.

Answer (score 0):

As a non-programmer and having looked at the myriad of ways, for a simple solution I'd recommend Webform Stripe - unless it is too simple for your needs.

My need is predominantly to collect payment over the phone but I can also use it for clients to purchase fixed price service.